# CKEditor5 block widget. How do I use elementToStructure for editing downcast?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm converting some CKEditor4 widgets to CKEditor5. These are block widgets and I've been generally following the [SimpleBox](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/tutorials/implementing-a-block-widget.html) example. I've been mostly successfully but the following seemingly simple situation has me stumped.

I'm basically trying to do this:

```
<div class="my-list">
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

or, to simplify it further:

```
<div class="my-list">
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

i.e, just a div with a specific class where we can enter content. My model is just this:

```
schema.register('myList', {
  isLimit: true,
  allowWhere: '$block',
  allowContentOf: '$root',
});
```

I can't seem to get the editing downcast right. The following sort of works:

```
conversion.for('editingDowncast').elementToElement({
  model: 'myList',
  view: (modelElement, { writer }) => {
    const div = writer.createEditableElement('div', {
      class: 'my-list',
    });

    return toWidgetEditable(div, writer);
  },
});
```

The problem is that it doesn't look or feel like a complete widget. It doesn't have the "type around" wrapper with the above and below insert buttons etc. I also can't "escape" from it while editing.

The other widgets I've built always have an inner wrapper. i.e., the model would have myList and then myListInner inside it. The editing downcasts would downcast myList to a container element using toWidget() and myListInner would be downcast to an editable element and use toEditableWidget(). That works great but to be compatible with existing markup, we only want a single wrapper for this widget.

I think my problem is the lack of a wrapping container element while editing.

The solution seems to be to edit downcast to a structure using the [elementToStructure](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_downcasthelpers-DowncastHelpers.html#function-elementToStructure) function.

I've tried the following:

```
conversion.for('editingDowncast').elementToStructure({
  model: 'myList',
  view: ( modelElement, { writer } ) => {

    const outer = writer.createContainerElement( 'div', { class: 'my-list__outer' } );
    const outerWidget = toWidget(outer, writer);

    const inner = writer.createEditableElement( 'div', { class: 'my-list' } );
    const innerWidget = toWidgetEditable(inner, writer);

    writer.insert( writer.createPositionAt( outerWidget, 0 ), innerWidget );
    writer.insert( writer.createPositionAt( innerWidget, 0 ), writer.createSlot() );

    return outerWidget;
  }
});
```

That crashes with `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parent')` from the innards of CKEditor when an instance of the widget is added from the toolbar. I haven't been able to get past that. I get the same result if I pass the inner element to the outer as an array as described [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/deep-dive/conversion/helpers/downcast.html#element-to-structure-conversion-helper).

It's not clear to me if elementToStructure is intended for editing downcast or just data downcast and where the toWidget() and toWidgetEditable() functions fit in.

I have considered and tried other ways to approach this. For example, have the two level model like my other widgets with the separate editing downcasts for the outer and inner but make the data downcast produce only a single level. I've struggled with that because the structureToElement examples are all making the view more complex than the model, not less complex. I can data downcast the outer to a `<div class="my-list"></div>` okay but it still seems to want a data downcast for the inner view wrapper which then gets "in the way". The upcast becomes more complicated too because it needs to produce a two level model from a single level view. To simplest way, if I could make it work, always seems to be to keep the model single level like the data view and just tweak the editing view to make the widget behave normally while editing.

I feel like I'm missing something simple. I'm trying not to make this more complicated than it needs to be.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was so happy to find this question when working on a similar problem - just to see, that there is no answer. After spending hours on creating a simple `<div>` I finally found the solution.

I'm using CKEditor5 39.0.1 for reference. So some info might be outdated for future readers.

The missing piece is hidden in a dropdown of the [DowncastWriter::createSlot api docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_downcastwriter-DowncastWriter.html#function-createSlot):

```js
const viewSlot = conversionApi.writer.createSlot();
const viewPosition = conversionApi.writer.createPositionAt( viewElement, 0 );

conversionApi.writer.insert( viewPosition, viewSlot );
```

Combine this piece with the information from the [elementToStructure deep dive docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/deep-dive/conversion/helpers/downcast.html#handling-model-elements-children):

```js
const paragraphViewElement = writer.createContainerElement( 'p', {}, [
   writer.createSlot()
] );
```

Now the following code for your example should work (not tested).

```js
conversion.for('editingDowncast').elementToStructure({
  model: 'myList',
  view: ( modelElement, { writer } ) => {

    // create editable element
    const inner = writer.createEditableElement( 'div', { class: 'my-list' } );

    // editable element needs a slot for the actual content
    const viewSlot = writer.createSlot();
    const viewPosition = writer.createPositionAt(inner, 0);
    writer.insert(viewPosition, viewSlot);

    // turn inner div into editable widget
    const innerWidget = toWidgetEditable(inner, writer);

    const outer = writer.createContainerElement('div', {
      class: 'my-list__outer'
    },
    // add inner widget, that already has a slot as children
    [
      innerWidget
    ]);

    // turn wrapper div into widget
    const outerWidget = toWidget(outer, writer);

    return outerWidget;
  }
});
```

> I also can't "escape" from it while editing.

The above solution creates a draggable and focusable widget with an editable inner widget. I couldn't figure out how to properly use keyboard navigation to enter and to escape it. Multiple inner widgets can be focus-cycled with <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. You can't escape from the the first inner widget with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Entering the inner widget from the outer widget is also not possible without using a mouse. I think, this is an issue, that should be fixed upstream as a default behavior for `toWidget` and `toWidgetEditable`.